# Finding overlapping ranges between two interval data

Tags: r, data.table

I have one table with coordinates (`start`, `end`) of ca. 500000 fragments and another table with 60000 single coordinates that I would like to match with the former fragments. I.e., for each record from `dtCoords` table I need to search a record in `dtFrags` table having the same `chr` and `start`<=`coord`<=`end` (and retrieve the `type` from this record of `dtFrags`). Is it good idea at all to use R for this, or I should rather look to other languages?

Here is my example:

```
require(data.table)

dtFrags <- fread(
  "id,chr,start,end,type
 1,1,100,200,exon
 2,2,300,500,intron
 3,X,400,600,intron
 4,2,250,600,exon
")

dtCoords <- fread(
"id,chr,coord
 10,1,150
 20,2,300
 30,Y,500
")
```

At the end, I would like to have something like this:

```
"idC,chr,coord,idF,type
 10,  1,  150,  1, exon
 20,  2,  300,  2, intron
 20,  2,  300,  4, exon
 30,  Y,  500, NA, NA
"
```

I can simplify a bit the task by splitting the table to subtables by `chr`, so I would concentrate only on coordinates

```
setkey(dtCoords, 'chr')
setkey(dtFrags,  'chr')

for (chr in unique(dtCoords$chr)) {
  dtCoordsSub <- dtCoords[chr];
  dtFragsSub  <-  dtFrags[chr];
  dtCoordsSub[, {
    # ????  
  }, by=id]  
}
```

but it's still not clear for me how should I work inside... I would be very grateful for any hints.

UPD. just in case, I put my real table in the archive [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx1bFCRksKRHTHAtb0M0dm8taG8/edit?usp=sharing). After unpacking to your working directory, tables can be loaded with the following code:

```
dtCoords <- fread("dtCoords.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
dtFrags  <- fread("dtFrags.txt",  sep="\t", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: I do not have a way to run R right now, but this problems seems interesting to me. and I think first divide data by chromosome and then I hope you do not have duplicate coord in the range, then make coord column based on start and position.then merge later with that coord. I will get back to the problem tomorrow, if it is not solved by that time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, it's very appropriate to use the [bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/) package [`IRanges`](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html) to deal with problems related to intervals. It does so efficiently by implementing [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). [`GenomicRanges`](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.13/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) is another package that builds on top of `IRanges`, specifically for handling, well, "Genomic Ranges".

```
require(GenomicRanges)
gr1 = with(dtFrags, GRanges(Rle(factor(chr, 
          levels=c("1", "2", "X", "Y"))), IRanges(start, end)))
gr2 = with(dtCoords, GRanges(Rle(factor(chr, 
          levels=c("1", "2", "X", "Y"))), IRanges(coord, coord)))
olaps = findOverlaps(gr2, gr1)
dtCoords[, grp := seq_len(nrow(dtCoords))]
dtFrags[subjectHits(olaps), grp := queryHits(olaps)]
setkey(dtCoords, grp)
setkey(dtFrags, grp)
dtFrags[, list(grp, id, type)][dtCoords]

   grp id   type id.1 chr coord
1:   1  1   exon   10   1   150
2:   2  2 intron   20   2   300
3:   2  4   exon   20   2   300
4:   3 NA     NA   30   Y   500
```

Comment: well, for the moment I get an error with the last command (`dtFrags[, list(grp, id, type)][dtCoords]`): `Error in '[.data.table'(dtFrags[, list(grp, id, type)], dtCoords) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), x must be keyed (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted) so data.table knows which columns to join to and take advantage of x being sorted. Call setkey(x,...) first, see ?setkey.` - but overall it seems to be a solution, I will try to sort it out, thanks!

Comment: sure, I did `setkey`, as in your code (and when I check by `key(dtCoords)` and `key(dtCoords)`, both return `"grp"`) - still the same error.

Comment: oups, it seems I made not very good sample dataset... For my real data, typical situation is that one fragment contains multiple coordinates - just add one more record to the `dtCoords` table: say, `50,2,250` - so that it will match the fragment #4 of `dtFrags` - in this case your code seems to give not the output I would expect...

Answer (score 3):

Does this work?
You can use `merge` first and then `subset`

```
   kk<-merge(dtFrags,dtCoords,by="chr",all.x=TRUE)
> kk
   chr id.x start end   type id.y coord
1:   1    1   100 200   exon   10   150
2:   2    2   300 500 intron   20   300
3:   2    4   250 600   exon   20   300
4:   X    3   400 600 intron   NA    NA


 kk[coord>=start & coord<=end]
   chr id.x start end type id.y coord
1:   1    1   100 200 exon   10   150
2:   2    4   250 600 exon   20   300
```

Comment: @Frank, the output is almost OK (it should be just `>=` and `<=` instead of `>` and `<`), but I can't use it for my big tables

Comment: Unfortunately my tables seem to be too big, I get this: 
`Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x),  : 
  Join results in 1447477452 rows; more than 519176 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)). Check for duplicate key values in i, each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try including 'j' and dropping 'by' (by-without-by) so that j runs for each group to avoid the large allocation.`

Comment: @VasilyA Is that a problem of size? I suspect that that error can be made to show up in a small reproducible example. I know I've run into it with a four-row data.table before

Comment: yes the size definitively matters, I'm afraid I can't use this solution in my case: I have 24 levels for `chr` field, so merging by only this field gives billion of combinations...

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should reformat your dtFrags so that, e.g., if you have intervals (250,350) for A and (300,400) for B, you create four records (A in 250-300, A in 300-350, B in 300-350, B in 350-400). Then you would have non-overlapping intervals and could probably use the roll= option. (I'm not that familiar with the use of `roll`.) Anyway, I'm still convinced that you can reproduce your error in a smaller example.

Comment: thanks @Frank, I will try to dig out about the `roll` option. 
 As for reproducing the error - I don't see how to do this with small example, but I added the link to my real data ('UPD' at the end of the post).