# Subset data.frames, merge subsets, and rbind for result

Tags: r, loops, merge, dataframe, subset

I am attempting to find `values` in `df2` that are within a percentage of the `value` in `df1`. These `dfs` are in long format and consist of the following columns / variables `State` (df1), `ID`(df2), `MM`, `variable`, and `value`.  I am matching `MM` and `variable` and including all `values` between the data.frames so that I can subset them later to select those within a percentage.

A solution for my problem can almost be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19748675/1670053), using merge and then subset to find the `values`. However, an additional bit of nuance does not allow me to use this solution as is.  `df1` is ~900 rows and `df2` is ~1,600,000 rows, if I try to `merge` all, r/my machine can't handle it.  However, subsetting each `data.frame` by `MM` and `variable` first and then merging, then subsetting, and finally rbinding all the intermediaries subsetted data.frames should produce my desired result.

Is there a way to subset `data.frames` then `merge` them, store result until through list of subsetted `data.frames` to merge and then rbind them?

I know dlply can make a list of subsetted data.frames, but I don't know if I should use to then create list back to data.frames to merge. Also, I don't know how I'd keep the subsetting and merging in order. There are up to 12 `MM` groups and always 4 `variable` groups, up to 36 subsets per `df`.

A for-loop or a function with a for-loop seems like it would work, but I don't know the right tools in r to make it so.

The example below performs the subset and merge for one (of up to 36) `MM` and `variable` groupings.

```
# for example, MM = 1 and variable = TMN
df1 <- structure(list(State = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AL", "NM", "PA"), class = "factor"), 
    MM = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L), variable = structure(c(2L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("RH", 
    "TMN", "TMP", "TMX"), class = "factor"), value = c(1.2, 2.3, 
    3.4, 5.6, 7.8, 9.1, 1.3, 2.4, 3.5, 4.6, 5.7, 6.8)), .Names = c("State", 
    "MM", "variable", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -12L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), MM = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 7L
    ), variable = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("RH", "TMN", "TMP", "TMX"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(1.2, 2.3, 2.4, 1.3, 3.4, 9.1, 4.7, 3.5, 7.8, 5.6, 
    6.9, 5.7, 8.5, 1.2, 4.5)), .Names = c("ID", "MM", "variable", "value"), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))

df1.tmn <- subset(df1, MM == 1 && variable == 'TMN')
df2.tmn <- subset(df2, MM == 1 & variable == 'TMN')
df1.df2.tmn <- merge(df1.tmn, df2.tmn, by = c("MM", "variable"))
# desired output example using one MM and one variable
df1.df2.tmn.sub <- subset(df1.df2.tmn, value.y < value.x*1.025 & value.y > (value.x-(value.x*.025)))

# dlply can make subsets from data.frames into a list, but 
MM <- unique(as.list(df1$MM))
VAR <- unique(as.list(df1$variable))
dlply(df1, c("MM", "variable"))
```

Answer (score 1):

From this part of your question:

> Is there a way to subset data.frames then merge them, store result
>   until through list of subsetted data.frames to merge and then rbind
>   them?

I assume you want to keep intermediate results or intermediate computations/subsets. If that is indeed the case, you can store the intermediate results in a file (for example a .txt or .csv file) and then read the file back when necessary.

You can write a data.frame, say my_df directly into a file like this:

```
write.table(my_df,"filename.txt", sep="\t")
```

Here, the columns of the data.frame are separated by a tab, but check out the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html) on this I/O command for more detail.

Whenever you want to load all the information into a data.frame, you just use the [read.table](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) command:

```
newDf <- read.table("filename.txt")
```

Hope this can help you.