# find if there is any overlap in R

Tags: r, overlap

I am trying to write function which compare the ranges in two data frames and find overlaps.
my data frames have three columns `V1,V2,V3` (the first one is chromosome number, the second is start coordinate, the third is end of coordinate).
lets say: `df1`

```
 V1    V2  V3
chr1   10  25
chr1   20  100
chr1   98  101
chr2   10  15
chr2   35  46
chr3   50  55
chr3   60  90
chr4   5   100

df2:
 V1   V2  V3
chr1  95  105
chr1  200 205
chr2  45  50
chr2  49  51
chr2  55  90
chr3  50  100
chr4  101 110
```

I wanna write function to find any overlap.

the function `find_overlap(df1,df2)` should return df1 with new column of overlap with df2 like:

```
df1:
 V1    V2  V3  overlap 
chr1   10  25    0
chr1   20  100   1
chr1   98  101   1
chr2   10  15    0
chr2   35  46    1
chr3   50  55    1
chr3   60  90    1
chr4   5   100   0
```

if i call `find_overlap(df2,df1)`

```
df2:
 V1   V2  V3   overlap
chr1  95  105   1
chr1  200 205   0
chr2  45  50    1
chr2  49  51    0
chr2  55  90    0
chr3  50  100   1
chr4  101 110   0
```

I would thankful if you tell me how can I do it in R?

(It would be better if the function returns vector of overlaps instead of adding new column)
Thanks.

Comment: dear @akrun, there are some packages for finding overlaps, but they are not work fully correctly on my data. for example they find if they fully overlap and overlook some parts. so i decide to write my own function.

Comment: Have you checked `IRanges` `GenomciRanges` etc.  Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748535/finding-overlapping-ranges-between-two-interval-data/19752720#19752720 may help

Comment: thanks @akrun, it is helpful.But, i tried `countOverlaps` in `IRanges` I can only find those with fully overlap. not very useful for my purpose.

Comment: look at GenomicRanges more closely. Actually the default overlap is "any", so not only is it not limited to full overlap, but the default isn't even what you claim.

Comment: @Cina I don't have the package `GenomicRanges` installed, but I was able to get the expected result with `data.table`.  But, I think it would be better with `GenomicRanges`

Comment: GenomicRanges functions of interest will be `findOverlaps` and `subsetByOverlaps`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's using a) `foverlaps()` function from `data.table` package, and `overlapsAny` from `GenomicRanges`. Although there are plenty of posts on Stackoverflow that should already get you there.

#### foverlaps

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

setkey(df1, V1,V2,V3)
setkey(df2, V1,V2,V3)

any_overlaps_dt = function(df1, df2) {
    olaps = foverlaps(df1, df2, mult="first", type="any", which=TRUE)
    as.integer(!is.na(olaps))
}

olaps_12 = any_overlaps_dt(df1, df2)
# [1] 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0

olaps_21 = any_overlaps_dt(df2, df1)
# [1] 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

#### GenomicRanges

You can install the package by following the instructions [here](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html).

```
require(GenomicRanges)
any_overlaps_GR = function(df1, df2) {
    gr1 = GRanges(Rle(df1[[1]]), IRanges(df1[[2]], df1[[3]]))
    gr2 = GRanges(Rle(df2[[1]]), IRanges(df2[[2]], df2[[3]]))
    as.integer(overlapsAny(gr1, gr2, type="any", ignore.strand=TRUE))
}

olaps_12 = any_overlaps_GR(df1, df2)
# [1] 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
olaps_21 = any_overlaps_GR(df2, df1)
# [1] 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

Check `?makeGRangesFromDataFrame` for an alternate method of creating GRanges object from data.frames.

Comment: thank you very much. I faced the problem ! when I implement it on my actual data the result is  `table(olaps_21): 424(as 0) 3254 (as 1)` but after expanding df1 by 3000 plus and minus range the result is:`1145 (as 0) 2533 (as 1) `. i just extend the range and it should cover more, logically but it decreases overlaps ! I wonder why?