# Select rows that represent the range between two positions so as to include only intervals that contain at least one position of another table

Tags: r, merge, set, data.table

I need to save the lines from "ref" only when the INTERVALS (start/end) contain (within) at least one "position" (start) of the "map" table:

Follow example to the "ref" table:

```
ref<-"chr start end
chr1 1 10 
chr1 20 30  
chr1 30 40 
chr1 40 50 
chr2 20 30 
chr2 40 50  
chr2 80 90"
ref<-read.table(text=ref,header=T)
```

Follow example to the "map" table:

```
map<-"chr start
chr1 1
chr1 3 
chr1 5
chr1 31
chr1 32
chr2 1
chr2 2
chr2 89"
map<-read.table(text=map,header=T)
```

And I need a final table like this (only with the INTERVALS containing at least one value from "map" table values):

```
final<-"chr start end
chr1 1 10 
chr1 30 40 
chr2 80 90"
final<-read.table(text=final,header=T)
```

note that I am taking into account the chromosome number as well. And, that the considered value is the interval between "start" and "end" values on "ref" and not only the "start" and "end" values themselves.

to solve the problem with the chromossome, I have considered the chr+start and chr+end like a "tag" and tag1, respectively.

```
ref$tag <- paste0(ref$chr, "-", ref$start)
ref$tag1 <- paste0(ref$chr, "-", ref$end)
map$tag <- paste0(map$chr, "-", map$start)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this topic 
"[Finding overlapping ranges between two interval data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748535/finding-overlapping-ranges-between-two-interval-data)"
"In general, it's very appropriate to use the bioconductor package IRanges to deal with problems related to intervals"
So, here you are:

```
library("GenomicRanges")
library("data.table")


gr1 = with(ref, GRanges(Rle(factor(chr, 
                                       levels=c("chr1", "chr2"))), IRanges(start, end)))

gr2 = with(map, GRanges(Rle(factor(chr, 
                                        levels=c("chr1", "chr2"))), IRanges(start, start)))

olaps<-subsetByOverlaps(gr1, gr2)

olaps <- as.data.frame(olaps)
col_headings <- c('chr','start', 'end', 'width', 'strand')
names(olaps) <- col_headings

final <- subset(olaps, select = c("chr", "start", "end"))

    > final
       chr start end
    1 chr1     1  10
    2 chr1    30  40
    3 chr2    80  90
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ref[ref$start %in% map$start | ref$end %in% map$start, ]
```

More verbose:

```
rows_to_keep <- ref$start %in% map$start | ref$end %in% map$start
rows_to_keep
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

ref[rows_to_keep, ]
#    chr start end
# 1 chr1     1   2
# 2 chr2     2  10
# 4 chr2     6  10
```

Comment: I know that the results in this example will be the same, but this command is not considering the chr (chromosome number)...

Comment: also, looks like that is not getting the interval between the map table.
"only when have some value in map (start) that is contained within the range of "ref" (start-end)).

Comment: @Fpertille both comments are true; however, those requirements were not apparent from the given example. At this point, I would suggest posting a new question and example dataset that illustrates those specifics.

Comment: I have to thank you for the good answer and sorry about the bad exemple, but the question that I asked was:
"I need to save the lines from "ref" only when the INTERVALS (start/end) contain (within) at least one "position" (start) of the "map" table.
I don´t should do a redundant new question according to stackoverflhow rules.

Comment: @Fpertille can you be more specific and edit your question? Give some examples of things that should "pass" that logic and things that should "fail" -- this sounds similar to some other posts: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19748535/2572423